# git add a maven project to a existing repository

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I work with Eclipse and Git. I created a maven project and now I want to add it to the git repository. This repository isn't empty.

The is Eclipse screen

[image]

I have some maven projects on the branch transfesa. I want to add the new Maven project to transfesa.

Answer (score 0):

Check your project on disk where it is created.

If it is inside your existing repository you simply can `git status` and it will show all the new files added under your new project.

If not then create you new projects with other projects(at sibling level hierarchy on the disk). This will let you add and commit new project to existing repository on your branch.

Comment: As you can see from the screenshot the project is not inside a Git repository. Your answer refers to the command lines Git (which might not be installed), whereas the question is about EGit.